# What state is fire? Solid, Liquid or Gas or Plasma?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, plasma-physics

What state is [fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire)? Solid, Liquid or Gas or Plasma?

I was just roaming around when this question popped out of my mind. In what state is FIRE?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23469/

Comment: Fire is a gas phase reaction. The link jinawee posted answers your question in some detail. Also see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51738/